# SIPAddHeader not work in sip or iax2 trunk

Tags: asterisk, trunk, freepbx, elastix

```
...
exten => In,n,SIPAddHeader(X-myname:tabesh)
exten => In,n,Dial(SIP/to133/109)
...
```

SIPAddHeader in internal extension to extension worked but it not work in sip or iax2 trunk.

Answer (score 1):

1) sip header works only for first invite, not for reinvite. Only for first invite after it called

2) sip header work only for sip. No, iax have no headers like that.

Comment: so, do i need to make dial before setting the header? cause i cant see the custom header in the sip messages

Comment: You should see it in FIRST message only.